# Internal Server Error should be more elaborate with Catalyst

Tags: perl, error-handling, catalyst

I've made a Catalyst application `MainSite` with `Bravo::MainSite::Controller::Root` controller.

To test it I added `package Bravo::MainSite::Controller::Test;` which basically only consists of:

```
sub catalyst_test :Global {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

    $c->response->body( "Catalyst works!" );
}
```

When I intentionally add an error to `Test.pm`, our CGI script

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Catalyst::ScriptRunner;
Catalyst::ScriptRunner->run('Bravo::MainSite', 'CGI');

1;
```

shows "Internal Server Error" without any clarification which is the exact error, instead of custom Catalyst error page but a basic Nginx or Apache error which is not detailed enough.

I want to see a more detailed error message.

Note that `-Debug` option is present in `use Catalyst`.

Comment: Internal Server Error generally means a fatal error in the application launched by Nginx/Apache. i.e., Catalyst crashed hard enough that it couldn't write a decent error message to the browser. Check the server error logs instead.